LLM Model not returning desire result after fine-tune with CSV Dataset
Im trying to fine-tune/train LLama3.2 with local csv.
these are step that ive done already :
Importing the required library :
import pandas as pd
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

setting the path from downloaded LLM file,tokenizer and loading it :
model_name = "D://LLama3.2_1B//"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

avoiding the padding error with :
if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token  # Use EOS token as padding token

Move model to GPU if available :
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)

creating custome dataset and filling it :
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)
class QADataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, tokenizer, max_length=512):
        self.data = dataframe
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        question = self.data.iloc[idx]['question']
        answer = self.data.iloc[idx]['answer']

        # Tokenize question and answer together for training
        encoding = self.tokenizer(
            question,
            answer,
            truncation=True,
            padding='max_length',
            max_length=self.max_length,
            return_tensors='pt'
        )

        return {
            'input_ids': encoding['input_ids'].squeeze(0),
            'attention_mask': encoding['attention_mask'].squeeze(0),
            'labels': encoding['input_ids'].squeeze(0)  # Labels for training
        }

df_qa = pd.read_csv('D://LLama3.2_1B_Dataset//graph.csv')
qa_dataset = QADataset(df_qa, tokenizer)

my dataset :
question,answer
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow"
"Who developed LLaMA models?", "Microsoft"

creating data loader and train model :
qa_loader = DataLoader(qa_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)
for batch in qa_loader:
    print(batch)
model.train()
for epoch in range(3):
    for batch in qa_loader:
        input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
        attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
        labels = batch['labels'].to(device)
        outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=labels)
        loss = outputs.loss
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        print(f"Epoch {epoch}, Loss: {loss.item()}")

output_dir = "D://LLama3.2_1B_output_dir//"
model.save_pretrained(output_dir)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(output_dir)

and this is how test my trained model in browser :
`from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, TrainingArguments,Trainer
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from datasets import load_dataset
import torch,json
app = Flask(__name__)
model_path = "D://LLama3.2_1B_output_dir//"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path)
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)
@app.route("/ask", methods=["GET"])
def ask_question():
    question = request.args.get("question", "")
    inputs = tokenizer(question, return_tensors="pt").to(device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model.generate(
        **inputs,
        max_length=450,
        num_return_sequences=1,
        no_repeat_ngram_size=2,
        top_k=50,
        top_p=0.95,
        temperature=0.7,
        do_sample=True
        )
    generated_text = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    json_response = jsonify(generated_text)
    json_response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    return json_response
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)`

And the model answer in not as same as dataset :

after i change dataset to this :
question,answer
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow1"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow2"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow3"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow4"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow5"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow6"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow7"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow8"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow9"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow10"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow11"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow12"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow13"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow14"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow15"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow16"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow17"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow18"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow19"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow20"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow21"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow22"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow23"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow24"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow25"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow26"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow27"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow28"
"What is the capital of France?", "Unknow29"

now i get "Unknown" answer for every question even the one not mention capital of france.

Just because your model has seen that the capital of France is "Unkown" 3 times, it is not enough for it to forget what it has previously learned (which already exists in the base model). how large is your data set and what is your exact goal ?

@KaranShishoo im starting with minimum dataset the one ive mentioned in question.
what realy concern me is that im doing the traning in a right way. if so i can make dataset larger to gives more correct answer.
